# My minecraft skin isn't showing up

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I open the launcher or minecraft.net, they both say my skin is applied, but when I load Minecraft, I can't see my skin or anyone else's skin. Also, when I load Minecraft, I have to end a suspended task to avoid crashing. This happens only on my client. My friends can see my skin. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is an old question, but what version are you playing? Surely by now (2024) it's a non-issue?